# How to identify & remove Invalid Objects in SQL Server database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, invalid-object-name

I have to work on a database in which there are many stored-procedures & views that are  referencing non-existing tables & columns. How can I get the list of invalid objects (Tables, Columns) so I can fix it accordingly?

Comment: You can use [SQL Server Data Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/tools.aspx) for this.

Comment: Thanks, SQL Prompt worked for me.

Comment: Until the evaluation runs out!

Comment: +1 for great advice. Let me try it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [SQL Prompt](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-prompt/) from Red Gate.  It has a *Find Invalid Objects* feature that identifies stored procedures and views (amongst others) that refer to non-existent objects and tells you why.

SQL Prompt is a commercial product -- you could use its 14-day fully-functional free trial period to tidy up your database right away though.

Disclaimer: I work for Red Gate (on the SQL Prompt team).